# Pixel modification on a Video frame in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, video, canvas

I am in the process of building an app for my research and I am new to canvas. I am trying to make a video out of a set of images and I need to be able to dynamically change a particular frame. I was successful in making the video but unable to modify a particular frame when I reach it. Below is the code for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Images with intervals</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="400" height="200" style="position:absolute;right:0; margin-right:auto; background-color:#bbb"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="400" height="200" style="position:absolute;left:0; margin-left:auto; background-color:#666"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var i = 0;
var im1 = 'images/img1.png';
function drawScreen() {

    context.drawImage(im1, 0, 0,50,50);
}

setInterval(function() {
  var im = ['images/img1.png', 'images/img2.png', 'images/img3.png', 'images/img4.png', 'images/img5.png'];
  // Create the image object
  var img = new Image();
  //alert(window["i"]);

  // If the image is loaded draw it on canvas
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  });
  //alert(window["i"]);

  // pass in the image source
  img.src = im[i++];
  alert(window["i"]);
  // if the image is last, change it back to the first
  i = i > im.length - 1 ? 0 : i;
  //alert(window["i"]);
  if(i==3) 
       { drawScreen();
         //alert(window["i"]); 
       }
}, 1000);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the value of i=3(meaning in 3 seconds according to the setInterval function), I am trying to display another image 'im1' as an example, which I am unable to do. I am new with HTML5 and canvas. Any help and suggestions here is deeply appreciated.

Comment: whne you reach the frame you want use getImageData from the whole canvas, edit the values and draw the new imagedate to the canvas http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: @dwana- The issue is that when I try to invoke the drawScreen() function, the following error occurs "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided." I don't get why the signature would be false.

Comment: try and replacing var im1 = 'images/img1.png'; with  var im1 = new Image();
im1.src = "images/img1.png";